# Mapping Collection of Mono to HashMap without blocking

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am new to Spring Webflux.

I am trying to write an aggregation service consuming from 2 legacy endpoints that don't support bulk queries.

- The first endpoint returns all accounts of a user (mono response). If it fails, the flow ends; no need to query the second endpoint.
- The second endpoint only takes 1 account number and returns its transactions (mono response).
- Transactions response doesn't contain account identifier, so my aim is simply generate a response like this:

```
@Value(staticConstructor = "of")
public class MyResponse {
   Map<String, List<Transaction>> accountTransactions;
}
```

My service now looks like this:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService {
   private final UserClient userClient;
   private final TransactionsClient transactionsClient;

   public Mono<MyResponse> getTransactions(..some relavant params..) {
       return userClient.getAccounts(..some relavant params..)
                        .zipWhen(accounts -> getTransactions(account))
                        .map(Tuple2::getT2)
                        .subscribeOn(boundedElastic());
   }

   public Mono<MyResponse> getTransactions(Accounts accounts) {
      Map<String, List<Transaction>> transactionsOfAccount = new HashMap<>()
      for (var account : accounts) {
         transactionsOfAccount.put(account.getName(), 
                                   transactionsClient.getTransactions(account)
                                                     .map(r -> {..some transformation..})
                                                     .subscribeOn(boundedElastic())
                                                     .block());  // Not happy with this
      }
      return Mono.just(MyResponse.of(transactionsOfAccount)) // Not happy with this
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do it in a non-blocking way?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run above code example. As far as I have understand from `getTransactions` you need only list of transactions without account name, so you can emit for each account a `List` of transactions and subscribe to it implicitly using `flatMap` instead of calling `block` and `subscribe` in called method

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService {
   private final UserClient userClient;
   private final TransactionsClient transactionsClient;

   public Mono<MyResponse> getTransactions(..some relavant params..) {
       return userClient.getAccounts(..some relavant params..)
                        .flatMap(account->getTransactions(account))
                        .subscribeOn(boundedElastic());
   }

   public Mono<MyResponse> getTransactions(Account account) {
 
        return transactionsClient.getTransactions(account)
                                  .map(r -> {..some transformation..})
                                 .collectList()
                                 .map(l->Map.of(account.getName(),l))
                                 .map(map->MyResponse.of(map));
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I really do need the account - transactions mapping for the frontend. I already mentioned that in my 3rd bullet point, transactions response does not contain account info.

Comment: @asli I have updated above code snippet by adding 2 `map` transformation stages, hope it will help. I guess `MyResponse` constructor can be updated to receive accounName and list of transactions  as parameters instead of Map, to avoid to 2 calls to `map` function.